# Mouse focus in java applet with some java versions

Tags: java, applet, oracleforms

We have written an application to run oracle forms java applets years ago.
The application works fine on forms versions 11.1.1.7.
But now we have on some sites a forms 11.1.2.x installed.
If we run the application with IE, firefox or chrome we don't have any mouse focus problems and everything runs fine. Also if we use java web start.
But if we run the application with our own written application we have mouse focus problems with jre 7 and 8. If we run the same application with jre 6 we don't have any problems at all.

I can't post all the code because it is too much code.

Can someone explain how it is possible that if we run the applet with a browser or java webstart it works fine with jre 8 and if we run it with our application with jre 8 it has mouse focus problems. And if we run it with jre 6 we don't have the problems?

---

**Update**

We just found out that a go_item in the first form we start is causing this error. If we click on another item in the first form before continuing we don't lose the focus.
We have tried putting a synchronize after the go_item but this doesn't seem to resolve the issue.

Comment: *"Can someone explain how it is possible that if we run the applet with a browser or java webstart it works fine with jre 8 and if we run it with our application with jre 8 it has mouse focus problems. And if we run it with jre 6 we don't have the problems?"*  Changes to the JRE.  That and well.. it is ***applets*** we are dealing with here.  *"I can't post all the code because it is too much code."*  Nobody wants you to post all the code.  ..

Comment: .. But for better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).